# Number of positive real roots of $a_1x^{k_1}(x+1)^{m_1}+a_2x^{k_2}(x+1)^{m_2}+\ldots+a_nx^{k_n}(x+1)^{m_n}-1$ is at most $n^2+n+2$

Tags: calculus, polynomials

I have the following problem.

> **Problem.** Given a positive integer $n$, positive integers $k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_n$, $m_1, m_2, \ldots, m_n$ and real numbers $a_1, a_2,\ldots, a_n$. Prove that polynomial
>   $$
> a_1x^{k_1}(x+1)^{m_1}+a_2x^{k_2}(x+1)^{m_2}+\ldots+a_nx^{k_n}(x+1)^{m_n}-1
> $$
>   has at most $n^2+n+2$ positive real roots.

I know that problems of this kind usually can be solved by applying Descartes' rule of signs, Rolle's theorem or differentiation. For example, the following problem

> **Problem.** Given a positive integer $n$, positive integers $k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_n$ and real numbers $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$. Prove that polynomial
>   $$
> a_1x^{k_1}+a_2x^{k_2}+\ldots+a_nx^{k_n}-1
> $$
>   has at most $n$ posititve real roots.

can be solved by using Descartes' rule of signs or by using Rolle's theorem with differentiation (just take derivative and cancel the lowest term of form $x^k$).

However, this approach does not help with the first problem because after differntiation the number of terms $ax^k(x+1)^m$ does not decrease (it can even become two times bigger).

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Interesting, but isn't the number of roots = the highest power of $x$? What would $n$ mean here?

Comment: We consider only positive real roots without multiplicity.

Comment: Can you give an example with $n=2$ and at least 4 positive real roots? The bound is $8$, so this should be easy...

Comment: I tried, but without success. Actually, I'm not sure if this bound is sharp.